# What is the speed of a derailed train somehow that landed on its wheels in Germany during WWII?

Tags: travel

The title pretty much gives it away-- what would the speed be of a derailed train on its wheels in Germany during WWII? Just so you know: the ground is covered with snow, and the train is just a normal train.

Comment: I'm glad you already have an answer, but this is in no way related to world building.

Comment: I am sorry, I must have misunderstood what the world building SE site was for.

Comment: Well. What is being asked is based purely in the real world, whereas this site is more about world building. I'm not one of the better welcomers, but I believe you can see for yourself if you check out the tags. Look at the questions being asked there, and check the 'meta site' or the chat room for more information. Especially the chat room, everyone in there is more than happy to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^

Comment: Impossible to say, since whether the train stays upright or not would seem to depend on how the derailment happens.  E.g. if someone removed both tracks ahead of it, the train might come to a smooth upright halt even if it was going full speed.  But if one rail was removed, it'd probably roll even at walking speed.

Comment: @SparklePony - Welcome to Worldbuilding!  If you have the specifics (train speed, terrain, etc) you could ask on Physics.SE I think.  If you have more to the story (I'm interested to hear more about it), try it out on our Sandbox:  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions  and this great community will help get it to you.  I think this could be a great question with a bit of tweaking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wheels are not captive in the [trucks](http://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/engines-equipment/diesel-locomotive8.htm), so if the train car is thrown off the tracks it will probably not land ready to roll. Only one car needs to have its wheels askew or mis-seated to ruin the whole thing.

So the speed will rapidly approach zero, and/or the train will tear itself apart before it gets very far.

Any wheels that *are* working normally are not designed for soil, and are in fact non-optimal for the purpose. They will sink into the ground or slice the ground, losing energy rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want some sort of time travel adventure where an accident makes a train jump back in time. You will have the usual problem that the Sun has moved *relative* to the center of the galaxy, Earth has moved *relative* to the sun, and any one spot on the Earth surface has moved *relative* to the center of the Earth. It is customary in time travel stories to ignore these problems and to assume that the travel is relative to the surface of the Earth.

Just prior to the incident, the train would have moved at the normal speed for the 21st century.

- [Local trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional-Express) can travel 120 to 200 kph.
- Slow [intercity trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_(Deutsche_Bahn)) can reach up to 200 kph, they are much more likely than local trains to travel that fast.
- Fast [intercity trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_(Deutsche_Bahn)) can reach over 300 kph, but they will be somewhat slower on most lines.

After the incident, you have a vehicle that was designed to travel on rails hurling over the snow. [This picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ice_eschede_1.jpg) involved a train and a bridge, but you get an idea of the aftermath.